# Logic app Azure retrieve data from Blob and save to Kusto

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-explorer

I have created a logic app to execute the sp and save the data in csv file now i need to read the csv file and save the data (ingest) into Kusto, I have added reading data from blob "when a blob is added or modified" but when it's executed i am getting empty data in body . Can any one help me what could be the mistake,

Comment: There could be various reasons why this may happen: incorrect data format is probably the most common one. It is also not clear where you see the empty body (is it in Kusto table? other place?)

Comment: i see empty data in Kusto table , I have created mapping using ingest with exact field names and data types i have valid data in my blob but data is not inserting into Kusto table

Comment: Step1 : pulling the data from blob.

step 2 injest into table but i see everything is completed without error but i dont see data in kusto table. 


 I am saving csv as blob file with comma separated and reading data and injest using file path with CSV mapping reference

Executing below query and passing the path in my logical app

concat('.ingest into table h"https://XXXAzure.blob.core.windows.net',triggerBody()?['Path'],';Storage_Key"',' with @''{"format":"csv","csvMappingReference":"InjustTableMapping"}''')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue with with Kusto csv mapping after i ran the Query in Kusto i am ble to fix the issue.

Comment: Could you please explain a little what was the problem and how did you solve it so others may use your solution please?